# Change domain name DNS host record

Tags: dns, domain

Is there a command to change where a domain name points to?

for example

```bsh
$ dn --change 209.85.128.65 --host-type dns-a --domain-name google.com --registrar markmonitor.com --config ./googleAtMarkmonitorCredentials.txt
```

Idk if I was understood

There can be `--host-type aaaa` too for example

Comment: You can use `/etc/hosts` but for local scope only.

Comment: @annahri the question is about a DNS record, not about a host entry :) these two have locally the same "effect", but are different things, as you note :)

Comment: Or maybe your 'DNS as a Service' provider may have an API that you can use.

Comment: @annahri I mean, changing it in the registrar, thats why theres a registrar argument. And some DNS providers have an API to change IP (like no-ip, etc...), but here I want to change it from my terminal

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no a single command – the domain is part of a zone, and someone "owns" the zone, and they're the ones operating their DNS server of choice.

It you're the one running your own DNS server, you'll have to refer to the documentation of that. For Bind, there's tools like `rndc`.

But I'm almost certain you're not a name server administrator. In that case: no, there's no such command, unless your domain server operator (usually: the company you pay for your domain, i.e. your registrar. But nameserver operator and registrar don't have to be the same...) offers you some programmatic access. That often happens through REST APIs, so there might be a single `curl` request you can send.

But, again, this is all specific to who is operating the service you want to modify. You will need to check with their documentation / customer service.

Comment: The REST API lead is good! Maybe I can tinker a little bit to send the same request as one that I send with my browser by hand, and with that modify the IP with a command. I have no hope that such registrar (that I use) have any advanced tools about that, but I'll see

Comment: just email them. They will tell you right away.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that practical because of configuration needed and hosting but for freenom you have github/docker repo that have programs to order such changes. Less practical than a simple command as I said

https://github.com/search?q=freenom

https://hub.docker.com/search?q=freenom&type=image